# How to get "session duration" group by "operating system" in Firebase Bigquery SQL?

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery

I try to get the "average session duration" group by "operating system" (device.operating_system) and "date" (event_date).

In the [firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement.html), they give us this query to get the average duration session

```
SELECT SUM(engagement_time) AS total_user_engagement 
FROM (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, 
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 
      "engagement_time_msec") AS engagement_time
  FROM `FIREBASE_PROJECT` 
)
WHERE engagement_time > 0
GROUP BY user_pseudo_id
```

This query give me the total user engagement by user ID (each row is a different user):

```
row|total_user_engagement
---|------------------
1  |989646
2  |225655
3  |125489
4  | 58496
...|......
```

But I have no idea where I have to add the "operating system" and "event_date" variables to get this information by os and date. I tried differents queries with no result. For example to get this result by operatiing system I tried the following

```
SELECT SUM(engagement_time) AS total_user_engagement 
FROM (
  SELECT device.operating_system, 
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 
      "engagement_time_msec") AS engagement_time
  FROM `FIREBASE_PROJECT` 
)
WHERE engagement_time > 0
GROUP BY device.operating_system
```

But it gives me an error message (Error: Unrecognized name: device at [9:10] ). In others queries device.operating_system is recognized.

For example in that one :

```
SELECT 
  event_date,
  device.operating_system as os_type,
  device.operating_system_version as os_version,
  device.mobile_brand_name as device_brand, 
  device.mobile_model_name as device_model,
  count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as all_users
FROM `FIREBASE Project`
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
```

What I would like to have as a result is something like this :

```
row|event_date|OS     |total_user_engagement
---|----------------------------------------
1  |20191212  |ios    |989646
2  |20191212  |android|225655
3  |20191212  |ios    |125489
4  |20191212  |android| 58496
...
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.  The columns that you mention are not shown in your query.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @GordonLinoff. I made changes with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably because you are referencing the variable `device` in the outer query, while this variable is only visible from the inner query (subquery). I believe the issue will be fixed by changing the last row of the query from `GROUP BY device.operating_system`
to
`GROUP BY operating_system`.

Hopefully this will make clearer what is happening here: the inner query is accessing the table `FIREBASE_PROJECT` and returning the field `operating_system` from the nested column `device`. The outer query accesses the results of the inner query, so it only sees the returned field `operating_system`, without information about its original context within the nested variable `device`. That is why trying to reference `device` at this level will fail.

In the other example you posted this issue does not appear, since there is only a simple query.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it works ! But I had to add the operating_system reference in the outer query as well. `SELECT SUM(engagement_time) AS total_user_engagement, operating_system,
FROM (
  SELECT device.operating_system, 
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 
      "engagement_time_msec") AS engagement_time
  FROM 'FIREBASE_PROJECT' 
)
WHERE engagement_time > 0
GROUP BY operating_system` But How can I add the event_date to have the final output I want ? When I add it in the outer query, I have again this error message "Unrecognized name". Thank you

Comment: That is probably because your inner query was not returning `event_date`. In order to group by `event_date` you should include it in the same places as `operating_system` or `device.operating_system`: the inner query results, the outer query results and the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time ! It works. The final code is `SELECT 
operating_system, 
event_date,
SUM(engagement_time) AS total_user_engagement, 
FROM ( SELECT device.operating_system, event_date,
  (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) 
  WHERE key = "engagement_time_msec") AS engagement_time 
  FROM 'Firebase Project'  ) 
WHERE engagement_time > 0 
GROUP BY event_date, operating_system`